# Why does `*mut T` implement `Unwindsafe` but `&mut T` doesn't?

Tags: rust, unsafe, stack-unwinding, raw-pointer

In the [documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/panic/trait.UnwindSafe.html#who-implements-unwindsafe) for `Unwindsafe` we have:

> Types such as `&mut` T and `&RefCell<T>` are examples which are **not** unwind safe. The general idea is that any mutable state which can be shared across `catch_unwind` is not unwind safe by default. This is because it is very easy to witness a broken invariant outside of `catch_unwind` as the data is simply accessed as usual.

Following this logic it seems to me that `*mut T` should not be `Unwindsafe`. But [it turns out that it is](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.pointer.html#impl-UnwindSafe). Why is that?

Comment: I'd guess it's because `*mut` doesn't in and of itself have invariants, so there's no "broken invariants" to observe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`*mut T` being a raw pointer, it has no invariant whatsoever.

It can be null, point to invalid memory, it is `Copy`, and you can have two of them pointing to the same area in memory.

There is nothing you can do mutably *and* safety with a `*mut T` anyway, so it has no reason not to be `Unwindsafe`.